# ValueError in fastparquet writer using engine="fastparquet"

Tags: pandas, dataframe, parquet

I encountered ValueError when using `to_parquet` with `engine="fastparquet"` generating the parquet file from the DataFrame.

```py
timestamp = dt.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%dT%H%M%S")
print('timestamp:', timestamp)
print('dataset_df:', dataset_df, type(dataset_df))

dataset_df.to_parquet(f"dataset_{timestamp}.parquet", engine="fastparquet")

#output
# timestamp: 20230213T163544
# dataset_df: [7001 rows x 51 columns] <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

The error message shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "c:\users\projects\prepro.py", line 320, in prepro
    dataset_df.to_parquet(

  File "C:\Users\user_name\.conda\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 211, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\.conda\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2975, in to_parquet
    return to_parquet(

  File "C:\Users\.conda\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parquet.py", line 430, in to_parquet
    impl.write(
    se, type = find_type(data[column], fixed_text=fixed,

  File "C:\Users\.conda\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\fastparquet\writer.py", line 126, in find_type
    object_encoding = infer_object_encoding(data)

  File "C:\Users\.conda\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\fastparquet\writer.py", line 343, in infer_object_encoding
    if pd.isna(i):


ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

However, there is no issues when replacing the engine with `engine="pyarrow"`. I learned that there are some differences in speed and pandas default engine for DataFrame objects is `pyarrow`, but does anyone know where does this ValueError come from?

Comment: It looks to me like you have numpy arrays as values of your pandas cell, and fastparquet doesn't do a good job at inferring what is their type.

Comment: Is there a way to disable inference of object encoding? (I need fastparquet over pyarrow because of its ability to append).